# How can you determine how frequently a function, aggregate, or trigger function is called in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Plain and simple, we have a database that has aggregates, functions, tables, trigger functions, views, etc. Getting usage information for tables and views is simple enough and documentation is easy enough to find, but as for aggregates, function, and trigger functions, it seems nigh impossible to find any documentation on a way to get usage information. The closest that I was able to find was essentially the same question but for SQL Server found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827058/how-often-is-stored-procedure-xyz-or-table-valued-function-used-sql-server-20), but that doesn't help with Postgresql.

So is it possible to get this information in Postgres? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the PostgreSQL documentation on runtime statistics (found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-statistics.html)).  It has a track_functions() setting that can be manipulated to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Your info got me on the right track to figure it all out. Like you said, track_functions() to turn it on, then something like 'SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_functions' to get the data.

Comment: This [link](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE) is useful for seeing how to get the data, just in case anyone else needs it.