# sp_settriggerorder in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012.

I have set up 4 update triggers and 4 insert triggers on my Data base tables.
and [sp_triggerorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx)
to set the order of the trigger.

I want to know how many times `sp_settriggerorder` run?

any help?

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what your question is. Could you make another attempt at re-phrasing it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: its actually nt a real scenario but appeared in my test today.. options `0,1,2,3,4`

Comment: There must be more to the question - such as a specification on what order the triggers are *meant* to execute in? Also, since it's a test, it's usually best for you to indicate what you *think* the answer is and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take help of [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx) to find out the Stored procedure usage

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name', 
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

> Note: An initial query of sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats might produce
>   inaccurate results if there is a workload currently executing on the
>   server. More accurate results may be determined by rerunning the
>   query.

From Mitch Wheat [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827097/298336)

```
SELECT  p.name AS [SP Name], qs.execution_count,
ISNULL(qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Second, qs.cached_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS [Calls/Second],
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [AvgWorkerTime], qs.total_worker_time AS [TotalWorkerTime],  
qs.total_elapsed_time, qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
qs.cached_time
FROM sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS qs
ON p.[object_id] = qs.[object_id]
WHERE qs.database_id = DB_ID()
AND p.name = 'sp_settriggerorder'
```

Alternatively,  You can use [Sql Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173882(v=sql.80).aspx) to capture the spastics.